# Stripe API - C#/.NET List All Customers problems with pagination

Tags: c#, .net, stripe.net

this might be a simple answer due to my inexperience with C# and .NET. I have two Stripe Test Accounts. TL:DR; is I am essentially looking for a Customers.all solution.

The source account has all the customer, card, and charge data.

The destination account has the copied card and customer data done by Stripe Support.

I have code that loops through the pulls all the data from the source account. It then finds the customer data from the destination account using the collection of customer/card data from the source. After that it then recreates the charges from the source account into the destination account.

I am able to successfully copy the first 100 charges into the destination account using information from the source account but I am having the hardest time getting the rest of the customers.

This is what I have so far:

```
public static void GenerateDestinationChargeData()
    {
        // code to get collection of customer data from destination account
        StripeConfiguration.SetApiKey(destinationTestKey);

        var customerService = new StripeCustomerService();


      IEnumerable<StripeCustomer> customerItems = customerService.List(
          new StripeCustomerListOptions()
          {
              Limit = 100,
              //this is what I cannot figure out, eventually to get all of the customers from the destination account
              StartingAfter = customerItems.LastOrDefault().Id
          }
       );



        // loop through collection of customers from destination acct to fetch customer charge data from source account
        foreach (var i in customerItems)
        {
            bool isError = false;

            var liveChargeService = new StripeChargeService();
            StripeConfiguration.SetApiKey(sourceTestKey);
            StripeList<StripeCharge> chargeItems = new StripeList<StripeCharge>();
            chargeItems = liveChargeService.List(
               new StripeChargeListOptions()
               {
                   Limit = 100,
                   CustomerId = i.Id
               }
             );

            // loop through customer charge data from source and re-create charge data on destination Acct
            foreach (var c in chargeItems.Data)
            {
                StripeConfiguration.SetApiKey(sourceTestKey);
                var emailReceipt = "";
                Dictionary<string, string> chargeMetaData = new Dictionary<string, string>();
                var onBehalfOf = "";
                var transferGroup = "";
                var chargeDescription = "";
                var chargeCaptured = "";
                var chargeCurrency = "";
                var chargeStatementDescriptor = "";

                if (c.ReceiptEmail != null)
                {
                    emailReceipt = c.ReceiptEmail;
                }
                if (c.Metadata != null)
                {
                    chargeMetaData = c.Metadata;
                }
                if (c.OnBehalfOf != null)
                {
                    onBehalfOf = c.OnBehalfOf.ToString();
                }
                if (c.TransferGroup != null)
                {
                    transferGroup = c.TransferGroup;
                }
                if (c.Description != null)
                {
                    chargeDescription = c.Description;
                }
                if (c.Captured != null)
                {
                    chargeCaptured = c.Captured.ToString();
                }
                if (c.Currency != null)
                {
                    chargeCurrency = c.Currency;
                }
                if (c.StatementDescriptor != null)
                {
                    chargeStatementDescriptor = c.StatementDescriptor;
                }

                try
                {
                    var chargeOptions = new StripeChargeCreateOptions();
                    chargeOptions.CustomerId = i.Id;
                    chargeOptions.ReceiptEmail = emailReceipt;
                    chargeOptions.Metadata = chargeMetaData;
                    chargeOptions.Description = chargeDescription;
                    chargeOptions.Capture = c.Captured;
                    chargeOptions.Currency = chargeCurrency;
                    chargeOptions.Amount = c.Amount;
                    chargeOptions.StatementDescriptor = chargeStatementDescriptor;

                    StripeChargeService chargeService = new StripeChargeService(destinationTestKey);

                    StripeCharge stripeCharge = chargeService.Create(chargeOptions);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Utility.NotifyDevAdminException("test", ex);
                    isError = true;
                }
                if (isError) continue;

            }

        }
    }
```

Thank you so much :)

Comment: The solution was pretty straightforward and I felt that I lazed out on the solution. I wrapped the customerservice codeblock in a while loop pushing the customers into an array and then iterating through that to finally recreate the charges

Comment: Hi Can you edit the answer, How you achieve it?

Comment: I am stuck in same problem

Comment: @AmmarAhmed post has been updated

Answer (score 1):

Since we cannot do a Customers.all with this current Stripe API, the solution is to set an empty variable and assign it the last Customer ID in the first set of 100 that we get and continue the query from that last assigned value

```
var lastId = String.Empty;

if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(lastId))
{
  StripeConfiguration.SetApiKey(sourceCustomerAccountAPIKey);

  customerItems = customerService.List(
  new StripeCustomerListOptions(){ Limit = 100 });
}
else 
{
  StripeConfiguration.SetApiKey(sourceCustomerAccountAPIKey);
  customerItems = customerService.List(
  new StripeCustomerListOptions() {
      Limit = 100,
      StartingAfter = lastId });
}

lastId = customerItems.LastOrDefault().Id;
```

Comment: Thanks That is helpful :)